# How do I get the current logged in user in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a [Google Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

In Chrome, [users can sign in](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?hl=en).

How do I get the current signed in user in Javascript? Specifically I want their name and picture to use in my extension.

Comment: Are you referring to _persons_ (Name + Picture) or Google accounts?

Comment: see chrome.identity and any oauth2 scope that would give you the google users info you need

Comment: Yes, Persons. As in who is signed in as shown by the button on the top right. And the image that is shown when clicking on that button.